# Kable function inside flexdashboard

Tags: r

i am running the below code. But i am not able to see output in the form of kable table. Not sure what wrong i am doing

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "bordered"))
```
````

Comment: I cant reproduce the error. I am getting the table. Are you sure you have all necessary packages installed and that there is no error raised?

Comment: Oops. Sorry I got. I re installed R . Now it is working. Thanks